# AutoHotkey - Command Prompt Issues

Tags: java, path, autohotkey, javac, java-8

so I have recently been using AutoHotkey and I am a fan as of now but I am running into a couple of issues. I usually compile and run my Java programs from the command terminal in Windows 7.
The paths for the compiler (`javac`) and to run the program (`java`) are set properly and run when I open command prompt without using AutoHotkey. But, as soon as I run an AHK script that opens up the command terminal from the same location and try and use the `java` command I get the following message

> Error: could not open 'C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jre7\lib\i386\jvm.config'

I understand that it would not be able to find this location considering I am running Java `1.8.5_05` but I do not know why the path is not working properly. The stranger part is that when I open a command prompt with AutoHotKey `javac` IS still recognized and running the correct version.

My question is this. Why am I able to successfully compile and run java programs when opening up the terminal when I click the `cmd.exe` icon but am UNABLE to run java programs when the terminal is opened via a simple AutoHotKey script?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Note: My systems path variable and user path variable are correctly set to `JAVA_HOME` which points to the `1.8.5_05` version

Comment: Show your `run` code...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try running cmd with the /c flag.

For example running this line of code...

```
run, cmd /c ping google.com
```

...will open a command prompt, ping google.com, then close the command prompt.